# SQL Powershell to Create Backup of Objects

Tags: sql, powershell

I would like to create a powershell script that I can run to backup objects to file before updating them.  My goal is to backup objects before changing them in case something breaks.  I would like to pass in parameters to run like the following:

backupobjects.ps1 -servername -databasename -schemaname -objectname -outputdirectory

So if I call this powershell script and pass in parameters the script will connect to the database and find the object and save the CREATE script and save the object to the outputdirectory passed in and put BEFORE_objectname.sql as the filename.

I am just starting in powershell so accepting parameters I have not learned yet.

Any guidance or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: So... what's your question? Have you tried creating the script? Is your question about passing parameters to powershell? Connecting to a database? You need to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write it for you, here are a couple of nudges:

1) param is how you pass in parameters in powershell.  I like to do it like so:

```
param (
   [string] $server = (Read-Host "Enter a server name"),
   [string] $db = (Read-Host "Enter a database name")
)
```

you then reference $server and $db later in your script as though you'd explicitly initialized them.

2) Most (if not all) objects in SQL server have a Script() method attached to them.  For instance take a look at the [Table class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.aspx).

3) You can control how objects are scripted using the ScriptingOptions class.  When you invoke the Script() method on an object, pass a ScriptingOptions object as an argument and the scripting behavior will be governed it.

Comment: That is cool, I will use your suggestions and see if I can get my script to work.

Is there an easy way to take in parameters without stopping and asking the user for input.

I would prefer to do it like the following:

scriptname.ps1 -servername -databasename -schema -objectname -outputpath

Is that doable?

Comment: You can do exactly that with the code that I provided.  If you pass in the parameters, it doesn't prompt.  If you don't, it does.